# Easily combine two ranges and a string in Excel through vba

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a simple way to combine the values of two ranges into one? I have a column of First Names and another of last Names that I would like to add together for a range of full names to be used in another workbook. I use Union to combine them, but I would also like to add a space between the two names.

```
   Set UnionRange = Union(Range1, " ", Range2)
```

Is there a way to use Union or something similar to add the space without having to loop through each row or write the results to the worksheet first?

Answer (score 0):

In order to concatenate two or more strings you can simply use `&` or `+` operator. In your case, assuming the range with last names is one cell to the right of the one with first names, and the concatenated string will be one cell further to the right, you could do something like this in VBA:

```
Sub concatenate_names
  Dim range_of_names As Range, c As Range, s As String

  Set range_of_names = Worksheets("Whatever").Range("Whatever")

  For Each c In range_of_names
    s = CStr(c) & " " & CStr(c.Offset(0, 1))
    c.Offset(0, 2) = s
  Next
End Sub
```

Of course, you don't strictly speaking need to store the string in a variable before putting it into the cell, but I find that it makes the code easier to read.

You can also do this via the worksheet-function [`CONCATENATE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/concat.php), putting something like this into the cell where the combined names should be:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1)
```

Comment: minor comment, but from a bad experience from inherited code, avoid using + to concatenate strings if there is any remote possibility the string may contain a number.   & works the same, so stick to a way that should never go wrong

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I want to save the result in a different workbook and would like to have the result in a range or an array. Do you know of a way to do this without looping through each cell?

Comment: Ah, I had missed that you didn't want to loop through the ranges - sorry, I should have read the question more carefully. As far as I know that is the only way you'll be able to combine the two ranges together though.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to loop?  If its a "speed" issue, you could read all your values into an array, loop through the array in a similar manner to what eirikdaude suggested, but writing the concatenated values out to a "target" array, then once finished, write your target array to your chosen destination.  Arrays are much faster especially when looping large numbers of cells, as looping cells is many I/O's where as reading an entire range into an array is 1 I/O and writing it back is also only 1 I/O